# Apply different function to key and value of a pair using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, mori

**tl;dr**: I'm looking for Ramda's (http://ramdajs.com) equivalent of Mori's [knit](http://swannodette.github.io/mori/#knit) function.

I want to apply a different function to the key and value in a key/value pair. This (contrived) example uses `mori.knit(f0, f1, ...)` to apply the `toUpper` function on the key and the `toLower` function on the value of a key/value pair:

```
const pairs = [ [ "key1", "VAL1" ], [ "key2", "VAL2" ], ... ]);
const result = mori.knit(toUpper, toLower, pairs);
// => [ [ "KEY1", "val1" ], [ "KEY2", "val2" ], ... ]
```

I'm looking for the equivalent using Ramda to apply a different function to the key and value of a key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda does not have precisely that function.  It's not hard to build something close.  Here's a version that is similar, with a slightly altered API and more generality:

```
const knit = compose(map, zipWith(call));

const pairs = [["key1", "VAL1"], ["key2", "VAL2"], ["key3", "VAL3"]];
knit([toUpper, toLower])(pairs);
//=> [["KEY1", "val1"], ["KEY2", "val2"], ["KEY3", "val3"]]

const triples = [["key1", "VAL1", 1], ["key2", "VAL2", 2], ["key3", "VAL3", 3]];
const square = n => n * n;
knit([toUpper, toLower, square])(triples);
//=> [["KEY1", "val1", 1], ["KEY2", "val2", 4], ["KEY3", "val3", 9]]
```

If you really want to pass the list in the initial call, you could write it like this:

```
const knit = useWith(map, [zipWith(call), identity]);
```

And if that version seems needlessly cryptic, you could always use a version that isn't points-free such as:

```
const knit = (fns, xs) => map(zipWith(call, fns), xs);
```

But none of these has a free list of functions; they're wrapped in a list.  That is the norm for Ramda functions.  If you really want one more like the mori function, your could add an `unapply`:

```
const knit = compose(map, unapply(zipWith(call)));
knit(toUpper, toLower)(pairs);
knit(toUpper, toLower, square)(triples);
```

---

My personal preference would be for the simplest one:

```
const knit = compose(map, zipWith(call));
knit([toUpper, toLower])(pairs);
knit([toUpper, toLower, square])(triples);
```

You can play with some of these variants on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?%2F%2F%20const%20knit%20%3D%20%28fns%2C%20xs%29%20%3D%3E%20map%28zipWith%28call%2C%20fns%29%2C%20xs%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20const%20knit%20%3D%20useWith%28map%2C%20[zipWith%28call%29%2C%20identity]%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20const%20knit%20%3D%20compose%28map%2C%20unapply%28zipWith%28call%29%29%29%3B%0Aconst%20knit%20%3D%20compose%28map%2C%20zipWith%28call%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20pairs%20%3D%20[[%22key1%22%2C%20%22VAL1%22]%2C%20[%22key2%22%2C%20%22VAL2%22]%2C%20[%22key3%22%2C%20%22VAL3%22]]%3B%0Aknit%28[toUpper%2C%20toLower]%29%28pairs%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20[[%22KEY1%22%2C%20%22val1%22]%2C%20[%22KEY2%22%2C%20%22val2%22]%2C%20[%22KEY3%22%2C%20%22val3%22]]%0A%0Aconst%20triples%20%3D%20[[%22key1%22%2C%20%22VAL1%22%2C%201]%2C%20[%22key2%22%2C%20%22VAL2%22%2C%202]%2C%20[%22key3%22%2C%20%22VAL3%22%2C%203]]%3B%0Aconst%20square%20%3D%20n%20%3D%3E%20n%20*%20n%3B%0Aknit%28[toUpper%2C%20toLower%2C%20square]%29%28triples%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20[[%22KEY1%22%2C%20%22val1%22%2C%201]%2C%20[%22KEY2%22%2C%20%22val2%22%2C%204]%2C%20[%22KEY3%22%2C%20%22val3%22%2C%209]]%0A)**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, this was exactly what I was looking for! cheers